# How to shift bins in a rose diagram using package 'circular' in R

Tags: r, rose-plot

I created a rose diagram of aspects in degrees for location data using the 'circular' package in R and the rose.diag function, with basic aspects of N, NE, E, etc., for a total of 8 bins. However, the bins do not straddle the aspects. In other words, the first bin goes from 0-45, the 2nd from 45 to 90, and so on, which is pooling the aspect data in strange ways. Is there any way to shift the bins so 0, 45, 90, etc are the center of the bins, instead of the edges?

```
rose.diag(Degrees$Degrees, bins=8,zero=pi/2, units = 'degrees', rotation='clock')
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without hacking the source code.  I seem to recall doing that at some point, but would have to excavate the code ...

Comment: @BenBolker  possible without hacking the source code but with hacking the plot:)

Answer (score 5):

I think Ben is right that it cannot be done easily with `rose.diag`, so here is a solution using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
Degrees <- runif(100, 0, 360)
rose <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Degrees)) +
  stat_bin(breaks = (0:8 - 0.5)/8 * 360) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:7/8*360, 
    labels = c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW")
    ) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
rose
```

[image]
This may not be ideal because not all of the features in `rose.diag` have easy equivalents in ggplot2.

Comment: see my answer for aversion with `rose.diag`

Comment: @agstudy your answer shows skillful manipulation of raw plot elements.  I personally prefer the appearance of the ggplot2 rendering and I find it easier to modify.

Comment: not. I am just answering the Op question to  to shift the bins. Maybe what I did is skillful, but I prefer my rendering:)

Comment: why not just shift around your initial dataset, and then compose your rosediagram with zero = (eg) pi

Comment: When using rose.diag I could use `points(mean(Degrees))` to add the mean direction. How can I do that using ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this using `gridBase` package. We keep using `rose.diag` and we `hack` the plot, once we are in the space of the good viewport.

[image]

```
require(grid)
#grid.newpage()
##generate some data 
x <- circular(runif(50, 0, 2*pi))
bins <- 8
rotation <- 'clock'
##tcl =0(no ticks), tcl.text=-2 to write away the ticks marks
rose.diag(x, bins=bins,zero=0,  rotation='clock',
          tcl=0,tcl.text=-2,col='#80FF00FF')
library(gridBase)
## I use the plot viewport
vp <- baseViewports()$plot
pushViewport(vp)           ## here we go!
## radial transformation 
at <- (0:bins - 0.5)/bins * 2 * pi

## ticks
grid.segments( x0 =  .95*sin(at),  y0 = 0.95*cos(at),
               x1 = 1.05*sin(at),  y1 = 1.05*cos(at),
               default.units = "native")
## ticks labels
grid.text(x = 1.1*sin(at),   default.units = "native",
          y = 1.1*cos(at),   gp=gpar(col='red'),
          label = c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"))
```

For visual aspect I add some tuning , but the some code above answer already to the question.

```
## dashed lines from the center for visual aspect 
grid.segments( x0 =  .95*sin(at),  y0 = 0.95*cos(at),
               x1 = 0,  0,
               gp = gpar(lty="dashed"),
               default.units = "native")

## circle just to get the same color of text
grid.circle(r=1,x=0,y=0,gp=gpar(col='red',fill=NA,lwd=2), default.units = "native")
## remove the viewport
popViewport(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not rotate your original data? N.b. below cdat is in degrees (zero = pi / 2), whilst zero is in 2*pi

rose.diag(cdat - 10, bins = 20, col="darkgrey", prop=1.3, axes=FALSE,
add=TRUE, zero = pi/2-pi/20)

Copy/pasting something I am working on:

```
library(circular)

raw <-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Andy\\Desktop\\business\\research\\Oxford\\MichelDish\\r.csv", header=T)
raw <-na.omit(raw)


cdat <- circular(raw [, c ("kandUnknown")],type="angles",units="degrees", rotation="clock", zero=pi/2)


plot(cdat, cex=1.1, bin=720, stack=TRUE, sep=0.035, shrink=1.8, tcl.text=.2)


ticks.circular(circular(seq(0,2*pi,pi/8)), zero=pi/2, rotation='clock', tcl=0.075)



rose.diag(cdat - 10, bins = 20, col="darkgrey", prop=1.3, axes=FALSE, add=TRUE, zero = pi/2 - pi/20)

lines(density.circular(cdat, bw=40), lwd=2, lty=1)
```

[image]

n.b. the code below gives you the old figure (above left):

```
rose.diag(cdat, bins = 20, col="darkgrey", prop=1.3, axes=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

ps for the curious, we are using such stats for eg http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950329315001068