# How to change y axis from count to percentage in rose diagram in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, orientation, circular-dependency, rose-plot

I created a rose diagram based on the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201891/how-to-shift-bins-in-a-rose-diagram-using-package-circular-in-r/14209622#14209622), but I need the y axis to show each bin as a percentage of the total. The data I am actually using is a vector of the different orientations of a group of animals. My example code currently would be something like:

```html
Degrees <- runif(100, 0, 360)
# 45 degree bins
rose <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Degrees)) +
  stat_bin(breaks = (0:8 - 0.5)/8 * 360, color = "black", fill = "light grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:7/8*360) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
rose
```

[example rose plot generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFR0m.jpg)

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add:

```
rose + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I need to be more clear - I'll give a clearer example for the Degrees vector
`Degrees <- c(10, 42, 60, 90, 92, 137, 182, 188, 220, 265, 268, 310, 320, 305)`

so there are three values that fall within 292.5 and 337.5, so rather than this showing up as, say, a count of 3, or 300%, I need it to show up as 21.42857%

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out: I've added a y aesthetic into stat_bin that seems to have fixed the issue.

```css
# 45 degree bins
rose <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Degrees)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), breaks = (0:8 - 0.5)/8 * 360, color = "black", fill = "light grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:7/8*360) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
rose
```

[Displays y as count/sum(count)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWHkR.jpg)